# SOQL SubQuery Parent-to-child-Junction Returns Child Records in Query Editor but not Apex. Any Idea why?

Tags: apex, soql, data

I have a Junction object for which I'm trying retrieve records in a subquery from one of it's parents and strangely the query returns child records when executing the query in SOQL Query Editor but it returns blank if executed via Apes.  Has anyone come across this before?  It's the same user running the query both times.

SOQL query executed in QUERY Editor (which returns Partner Relations)

```
Select Id, Name, (SELECT ID, Request__c FROM Partner_Relations__r) FROM Request__c
```

The equivalent executed in Apex

```
System.debug('Hello what values ' + [Select Id, Name, (SELECT ID, Request__c FROM Partner_Relations__r) FROM Request__c]);
```

The Apex query returns

> Request__c:{Id=a1R1q000001BkHoEAK, Name=R-0003238,
> RecordTypeId=0125I000000pEmgQAE, CurrencyIsoCode=USD},
> Request__c:{Id=a1R1q000001BkHuEAK, Name=R-0003240,
> RecordTypeId=0125I000000pEmhQAE, CurrencyIsoCode=USD})

I haven't even queried `RecordTypeId` or `CurrencyISOCode` :)

Does anyone know why the child records would not return in Apex despite returning in a general SOQL Editor?

The above Apex is just a simplified example as run in Execute Anonymous. The full query was returning blank child records in a function I had also.  As the same user runs both I was a bit confused :)

Thanks in advance for any pointers on why this may be occurring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.debug` is not printing out to log children's records. if you want to debug it, you need explicitly iterate children.

```
List<Request__c> requests = [
    Select Id, Name, (SELECT ID, Request__c FROM Partner_Relations__r)
    FROM Request__c
];

for(Request__c req :requests){
    for(Partner_Relation__c partnerRelation : req.Partner_Relations__r){
        System.debug('partnerRelation: ' + partnerRelation);
    }
}
```

---

`Id` always, `RecordTypeId`, if there is any record type on sobject and  `CurrencyISOCode`, if you have multicurrency enabled, are always automatically added to any `SOQL` query.

Comment: +1 Also, JSON.serialize, etc can expose this additional data.

Comment: Thanks all. Appreciate your help as always.